# highest weight of $\Lambda^k V$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I have a question regarding the highest weight of $\Lambda^k V$. Suppose I have an irreducible $\mathfrak{g}$-module, $V$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie Algebra with highest weight $[a_1, \cdots, a_n]$. I would like to know what the highest weight of $\Lambda^k V$ will be in terms of the highest weight of $V$ and what is the intuition and reasoning for it.

For $S^kV$, it is clear to me that $[ka_1, \cdots, ka_n]$ is the highest weight since if $v$ is the highest weight vector of $V$ then the highest weight vector of $S^kV$ will be $v^{\otimes k}$ and so the weight will be multiplied by $k$. Any insight will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a bit complicated because it depends on the weights present in $V$ and also their multiplicities. The answer is the highest possible sum of (the weights of) $k$ linearly independent weight vectors. But, because some weights appear with multiplicities $>1$ those $k$ vectors need not all have distinct weights. Of course, for $k>\dim V$ the exterior power becomes trivial.

Comment: Thank you! I believe I see this in the case of the standard representation, but I need to think more in the case of the adjoint representation!

Comment: You need to be a bit careful with the term "the highest weight". Any (finite dimensional) representation will have a highest weight vector, but unless it is irreducible, this need not be uniquely determined up to a scalar. Try out the example of the adjoint representation $W$ of $sl_3$, which has the highest root $\alpha_0 = \alpha_1+\alpha_2$ as its highest weight. In $\bigwedge^2 W$ we now have two possibilities for a highest weight vector using the description given by @JyrkiLahtonen, $\alpha_0\wedge\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_0\wedge\alpha_2$, and these generate different subrepresentations.

Comment: But even more, the vector $\alpha_1\wedge \alpha_2$ is also a highest weight vector, since any upper triangular matrix will kill at least one of $\alpha_1$ or $\alpha_2$, and this vector is not of the form given, so finding all highest weight vectors becomes even harder. (note that I am abusing notation somewhat badly here by writing the roots instead of the actual weights vectors with those roots as weights).

Comment: What Tobias says is, of course, correct. In general there will be several highest weight vectors (the order is not total).